# Creating a universal app on xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am a new iphone learner. I have been reading tutorials but it seems that none so far has answered few of my questions.

Kindly please if anyone can answer few of them or If anyone has better tutorial please post here.

1- In xcode 4.2 you can't have different iphone and ipad folders so almost all tutorials are useless. Now i want to create a universal application. How Am i suppose to do this. How can i create two xib files each for IPad and Iphone e.g I have A class named as LoadingPage.

2- Iphone 4 and Iphone 3 has different resolutions. How can I set these resolutions.

3- Initially I have created a universal empty application. What i got is `AppDelegate`. Now I want to show my Loading page which is a `UIViewController Class`. How will i make the class and view run once i open the appliction.

Here I used the code after reading some articles.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    firstView = [[Loading alloc]init];
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.firstView;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

My Delegate.h file has values

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *firstView;
```

This code worked fine but then it started giving error at main.m `Program Received signal SIGABRT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems xcode 4.2 uses only one appdelegate and use storyboards instead. The tutorials i was following were for previous versions of xcode.

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html) will guide you through your quest for creating universal apps

and if you want to convert an existing app to universal app go through [this tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/4/7/converting-to-a-universal-app-part-i.html)